# How to ensure, using regex, that a string doesn't begin with

Tags: regex

I have code with both angular.module and module, I am trying to make sure I only get module. I tried `(?!\.)(module)` using regex but when it is .module it still matches.

https://regex101.com/r/snO65F/1

How can I just match ones that do not have a period?

Comment: If it is not JS, use a lookbehind [`(?<!\.)module`](https://regex101.com/r/snO65F/2). In JS, you can use `(^|[^.])module`

Comment: If it's, as the title says, as well as your test string, is at the beginning of the string, just test for `^module´. [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/snO65F/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it was in Intellij but thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!)` defines a negative *lookahead*.

Use `(?<!)` instead (negative *lookbehind*), assuming your regex engine supports that.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/snO65F/3)